# $.ajax() function returns whole page , and can not delete row from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to delete a row from records using ajax but can't delete row and `$.ajax()` function returns the whole page instead of deleting row.

**Html code**

```
<tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class="center ">0</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="2" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gradeX even">
        <td class="sorting_1">3</td>
        <td class=" ">sarees</td>
        <td class=" ">contains sarres</td>
        <td cl="center ">1</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="3" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[name="deleteRecord"]', function(){

     var id= $(this).attr('id');

     if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
     $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category',
      data: {id:id},
      success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
  });
 }
});
```

**Php code**

```
 if($mode=='delete_category')
    {
       $id=$_POST['id'];

       $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
        if($q) {
                echo "YES";
              }
              else 
              {
                echo "NO";
              }
    }
```

Comment: what does `$mode` have ?

Comment: have lots of delete operation in one page , so its checks for category delete.

Answer (score 1):

if($_GET['mode'].=='delete_category') // variable in query string are taken as $_GET
    {
       $id=$_POST['id'];

```
   $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
    if($q) {
            echo "YES";
          }
          else 
          {
            echo "NO";
          }
}
```

and as you have echo YES or  NO in response in alert you will get that only
if you want deleted row store before deletion and echo that..

Comment: how can i get row deleted from database ?

Comment: if($_GET['mode'].=='delete_category') // variable in query string are taken as $_GET { $id=$_POST['id'];

can't understand what you said.

Comment: if($mode=='delete_category')
    {
       $id=$_POST['id'];
       
       //Get deleted Row value and store in array
       $deleted_row;
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);       
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $deleted_row =  $row;
        }
        
        
       $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
        if($q) {
                echo $deleted_row;
              }
              else 
              {
                echo "NO";
              }
    }

Comment: admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category
in this after  '?' what ever there is ,it is called query string.
and if we want to take that  variable it have to be accessed by $_GET

Comment: thank you , but its is the same as you told already.
$mode=$_GET['mode'];

Comment: You need to `$results = $q->execute();` to actually run the statement. and retrieve a DB result.

Answer (score 0):

`$mode` should be `$_GET['mode']`.

Alternatively, change `url:'admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category',` to `url:'admin_operation.php',` and change `data: {id:id},` to `data: {id:id, mode:'delete_category'},` and set `$mode = $_POST['mode']`.

If this is not working, then you are probably already echoing things to the page. We would need to see the code in the context of the rest of the file to determine if you are already echoing things to the page. Also, as others have pointed out, you should `exit;` at the end of the if block or after each echo to avoid returning code from later in the file.

Comment: hi , i have this set in top of the page.

Comment: Also, based on what you are saying about 'multiple delete operations', you should probably have this in a case/switch statement `switch ($mode){ case 'delete_category': ... break; default: ... break; }` so that only one should operate at a time.

Comment: @JAL, that is passed as a query string, so it should be in $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set `dataType` in `$.ajax` method.

```
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category',
      data: {id:id},
      dataType: 'json', // <-----
      success:function(data) {
        console.log(data); // should be something like {'status' : 'YES'}
      }
  });
```

And in your php code, you need to use `exit` statement after `echo`

```
if($mode=='delete_category')
{
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
  $output = array('status' => 'NO');
  if($q) {
    $output['status'] = 'YES';
  }
  echo json_encode($output);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I just updated the answer, pls try `console.log(data)`. It should be something like `{'status': 'YES'}`

Comment: Did you try `console.log(data)`? If yes, pls provide the output